# Missing monitoring metric values on Microsoft.Automation resource

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-automation

I want to retrieve monitoring metric values of Azure resources using [Microsoft Monitor API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-rest-api-walkthrough).

I use [Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor) nuget package (version 0.18.1-preview).

I try to retrieve metrics from [Microsoft.Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-supported-metrics#microsoftautomationautomationaccounts) resource. Microsoft Automation resource has `TotalJob` metric as described in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-supported-metrics#microsoftautomationautomationaccounts).

Also I can confirm it because I have retrieved metric definition of Microsoft.Automation resource. I used `MetricDefinitions.List` [method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.monitor.metricdefinitionsoperationsextensions.list?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Management_Monitor_MetricDefinitionsOperationsExtensions_List_Microsoft_Azure_Management_Monitor_IMetricDefinitionsOperations_System_String_). And all works fine.

But when I use `Metrics.List` [method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.monitor.metricsoperationsextensions.list?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Management_Monitor_MetricsOperationsExtensions_List_Microsoft_Azure_Management_Monitor_IMetricsOperations_System_String_Microsoft_Rest_Azure_OData_ODataQuery_Microsoft_Azure_Management_Monitor_Models_MetadataValue__System_String_System_Nullable_System_TimeSpan__System_String_System_String_System_Nullable_Microsoft_Azure_Management_Monitor_Models_ResultType__) then I can't retrieve any metric values. I have always `null` values in the response.

My code snippet is here:

```
var subscriptionId = "<MY_SUBSCRIPTION_ID>";
var resourceGroup = "Compute";
var resourceName = "cm-auto";

var resourceId = $"/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroup}/providers/Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/{resourceName}";

using (IMonitorClient client = _azureMonitorClient.GenerateConnectionInformation(account, resource))
{
    var definitions =client.MetricDefinitions.List(resourceId); // It works correctly

    var timeSpan = $"{DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-3):yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mmZ}/{DateTime.UtcNow:yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mmZ}";
    var interval = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
    var aggregation = "Total";
    var metric = "TotalJob";

    var values = client.Metrics.List(resourceId, metric: metric, timespan: timeSpan, interval: interval, aggregation: aggregation); // There I have always null values in the response result
}
```

Also you can see debug information on screenshots.
[image: definitions of my resource]
[image: metric values of my resource]

As you can see I have `null` values for `TotalJob` metric.

I have jobs which worked one hour ago. But I don't see any information about the jobs.

I don't understand why I don't see any metrics values.

**Where is my mistake?**

NOTE: I have checked my code on other Azure resources like [Microsoft.Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-supported-metrics#microsoftstoragestorageaccounts), [Microsoft.DocumentDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-supported-metrics#microsoftdocumentdbdatabaseaccounts), [Microsoft.Network (Traffic Manager)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-supported-metrics#microsoftnetworktrafficmanagerprofiles).
And my code with all these resources works fine. I can see metric values.

**I do not see metric values only on Microsoft.Automation resource.**

Comment: Can you confirm whether the metric data is showing up for the Microsoft.Automation resource in the Azure Portal?  Is this an issue where metrics are not working for Microsoft.Automation resource at all?  Or just with retrieving it via the SDK?  If metric data isn't working at all for this resource, you will need to open a support ticket.

Comment: @AndyShen I can see Activity Log and Job Statistic on Azure Portal. Please review a [screenshot](https://prnt.sc/htpi1r). I have tested my code snippet with wide time interval more than 48 hours (from 27 Dec to 29 Dec). But I did not see any metric values from SDK.

Comment: That screenshot shows Activity Log and Job statistic, not metric statistics.  Do you have a screen shot where metric charts show the data correctly?  In the Azure Portal, browse Azure Monitor -> Metrics (preview).  Based on a description of your issue, my theory is that there is some issue with the Microsoft.Automation metric on your resource and it will involve opening a support ticket for the platform team to investigate.

Comment: @AndyShen please look new [screenshot](https://prnt.sc/hu8g8j). There is no any metrics.

Comment: This suggests that metrics are not working for this resource.  You will need to open a support ticket for Microsoft Automation team to investigate.